# Trigger doesn't trigger when the form is sent to the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to create a trigger for getLastFormAddition(), but it doesn't trigger when the response arrives, I do have a trigger which is triggered when the form is sent:

```
function createFormTrigger()
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('getLastFormAddition')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();

    Browser.msgBox("Trigger created");
}
```

When I run the trigger it say's that the trigger is created.

My function to be fired when the form is received is as follows:

```
function getLastFormAddition()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ОТЧЕТЫ");
  var names = sheet.getRange("C3:C").getValues();
  var lastNamesIndex = names.filter(String).length;
  var rowRange = sheet.getRange(lastNamesIndex + 3,  1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(lastNamesIndex + 3, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  Browser.msgBox(rowValues);
}
```

For now I've set it up with the `Browser.msgBox()` but would like to add sheet creation functionality later down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getLastFormAddition(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  let vs = e.values;
  vs.shift();
  Logger.log(vs);
}
```

Your trigger code looks okay to me.  I tried it exactly the way you have it and it works just fine.  I'm thinking that may be you are missing the trigger because you are not looking at the spreadsheet and your code is hanging waiting for you to type ok to the alert.

You should  be able to see the response now in the executions log.  And it's better to get the data associated with  a submission from the trigger because if you have multiply simultaneous triggers the first one may actually be finding the last one's data by reading the spreadsheet instead of looking at e.values.